# SSRS report with Excel datasource

Tags: excel, reporting-services, odbc

I have been able to create an SSRS report using an Excel worksheet with ODBC drivers. However, the report does not refresh as the Excel worksheet changes daily. The preview of the data in Visual Studio shows the data from the day I created the SSRS report.

My connection to the Excel sheet is successful. Is there another step that will prevent the SSRS report from using cached data and force it to use the current data?

Comment: How are you consuming your report, from the VS designer or the Report Server ?

Comment: VS designer in preview for now.

Comment: Have you tried moving/deleting the "*.data" files next to your reports?

Comment: The data file is on the same server but in a different directory. Should that make a difference?

Comment: @Sébastien Sevrin meant that there is a **.data** file (not the Excel file) in your SSRS RDL file directory with the same name as your RDL file. SSRS creates this when a report is run. Sometimes Visual Studio will rely on this old **.data** file instead of getting the new data from your Excel file.